# How to visualize (polynomial) long division with infinite fractions only for the first n fractions

Tags: math-mode, polynom, polynomials

I have the following fraction `(1+2z^{-1})\(1+2z^{-1}+4z^{-3})` which I want to calculate and visualize with the `polynom`-package. However, if I execute the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polyset{style=C, div=:,vars=z}
    \polylongdiv{1+2z^{-1}}{1+2z^{-1}+4z^{-3}}

\end{document}
```

I will only get the exact solution:
[image: polylongdiv]

How can I output the first n fractions, like `1-4z^(-3)+8z^(-4)-16z(-5)+...` (in this case) with respect to intermediate steps, that will be made in order to obtain these fractions? *(If this doesn't work with the `polynom`-package I would be glad if you could mention packages, which will do the job!)*

Comment: This question essentially asks to implement truncated Laurent expansion at 0.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you are right. Should I change the title?